# Share my git repository

Tags: git, version-control, project-management

Hello 
I start new project and I want to use git for source control. I make new folder and use command: `git init` to init repo. How can my partner to clone my repo? 
Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are already a lot of blog posts and tutorials covering such a basic question.

Just two examples:

- http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/24/sharing-your-changes.html
- http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository

Answer (score 1):

If you want something super basic and even git daemon is too much for you, then you can just create a unix permission group, add both users to it, create a folder and set the gid flag, and then init your git repos in there. Then you need to add a post-update hook to ensure files are always group writable.

## Create the repository folder

Something like this. `coders` is the group you're creating. `yanev` and `venay` are users. `~/shared` is where you're storing your git repos. Do this setup once.

```
groupadd coders
useradd -g coders yanev
useradd -g coders venay
mkdir ~/shared
chgrp coders -R ~/shared
chmod g+s -R ~/shared
```

## Script to create git repos

Execute this in ~/shared each time you want to create a git repo.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Create a repo that will be accessible to everyone in the group.

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
    echo Error: Need name of repo to create
    exit 1
fi

name=$1

# Create the repo
git init --bare $name

# create the hook to ensure 
hook=$name/hooks/post-update
echo -e "#!/bin/sh\n#\n# Ensure that everything's writable\n\nchmod g+rw -R $PWD/$name/\n" > $hook
chmod a+x $hook

# Start everything with group rights
chmod g+rw -R $name
```

Use like:

```
cd ~/shared
./create_shared project
```

## Cloning

```
cd ~/code
git clone ~/shared/project
```

(Your partner will have to use the absolute path to your home folder.)

## Realize that's too much work and use git daemon

You should probably just use [git daemon](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon). If it doesn't work on your network (i.e., at university), talk to your IT staff about getting it working. : )

Comment: git daemon was perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of possible ways. the easiest, but not the best approach is 'git daemon'

You can find other options  [here](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/)